# Significance of a PATH explained

Tags: c#, java, python, path

This is probably a rudimentary question but I am still kinda new to programming and I've wondered for awhile. I've done multiple projects in Python, C#, and Java, and when I try to use new libraries (especially for Python) people always say to make sure its in the right PATH and such. I just followed an online tutorial on how to install Java on a new computer and it rekindled my question of what a path really is. Is the Path just were the programming language looks for a library in the file system? I get kinda confused on what it's significance is. Again, I'm sorry for the wide question, its just something that I've never quite gotten on my own programming.

EDIT: I just wanted to thank everyone so much for answering my question. I know it was a pretty dumb one now that I've finally figured out what it is, but it really helped me. I'm slowly working through as many C#, Java and Python tutorials as I can find online, and it's nice to know I have somewhere to ask questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PATH is a file directory on your computer. If you need to install a programming language, you might need to put it in your system PATH variable. This means that the system looks to these files for different information, IE where the libraries for the code you are using are.
Hope that helped!

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... Is the path were it looks for the library? For instance, if I import "pyserial" in a py script, does it look for its path to figure where the library actually is installed?

Comment: Yes. It the "path" tells the compiler where on your computer a file is located. So in C, if you type `#include <stdio.h>` then this actually tells the compiler to look for a file named `stdio.h` somewhere on your file system, to include code from the file. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, it did! I'm the only one of my friends who does this stuff on my own, so it helps to have simple stuff like this explained to me. YouTube only teaches me so much :)

Comment: Don't forget to give an up vote and a "Answered question" check! It gives you reputation, too!

Answer (score 5):

The `PATH` is an environment variable which the [shell (or other command interpreter)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_interpreter) uses to search for commands. Usually (always?) commands are found with a greedy algorithm, so entries that come first in the `PATH` are returned first. For example, a command in `/usr/local/bin` will override a command in `/usr/bin` given a `PATH` such as

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

while the purpose is consistent, the syntax is slightly different on WINDOWS - you would use

```
C:\> ECHO %PATH%
```

to "echo" your `PATH`.

First my shell is going to search `/usr/local/sbin` then `/usr/local/bin` then `/usr/sbin` and then `/usr/bin` before searching `/sbin` and `/bin` if the command isn't found then it will report that it couldn't find such a command...

```
# Like so
$ thisprogramdoesntexist
thisprogramdoesntexist: command not found
```

Now, on Linux at least, there's also a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which the system will use to search for dynamic libraries (greedily), on Windows I think it just uses the `PATH`. Finally, Java uses a `CLASSPATH` which is similar (but used to search for classes and JARs).

On Linux one might add an entry to the PATH like so,

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/addNewFolder"
```

While on Windows you might use

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\addNewFolder
```

Sometimes, you might manipulate your `PATH`(s) to enable specific functionality, see `update-java-alternatives` on Ubuntu for an example.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I didn't really get that it was pointing to somewhere else in the system, but that makes sense. Thanks Elliot!

Comment: Nice answer to the question, all though could be clearer, especially since the user may not understand the commands, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource (so far) about `PATH` information, you can see in this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Stack Overflow is not the best place to search about this, always check the amazing 
https://superuser.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: I think it would be nice to include some explanation, a link-only answer is not much of a good answer :)

Comment: it's because this question is more relative to superuser than stackoverflow, this isn't a programming issue.

Comment: Flag it for migration, then. I myself doesn't see a problem with it being asked here.

Comment: This question was already replied there, why to migrate a duplicated question?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as other said, `PATH` is a list of folders that is included in the search -other than the current folder- and you can always access straight away. It's one of the [Environment Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

For example, we have the python folder in `C:\Python27`. I'm sure you know that to run a python file, we commonly use `python script.py`.

What happens is that the command line searches for `python.exe` in your current folder, and if not found, search it in the folders in the path variable.

To read the path, you can, straightforwardly use:

```
$ PATH
```

If you're on windows, like i am, an easy way to deal with this is to just use System Properties. Just type it in the start menu, open it, and go to the 'advanced' tab. Click on the Environment Variables, there! You'll see a `PATH` variable, and you can modify it as you want.

I myself use more than one version of Python, and to deal with this, i appended all the folders to `PATH`, and changed my `python.exe` to `pythonversion_number.exe`. Problem solved! Now, i can run this in the command line:

```
$ python26 script.py
$ python33 script2.py
```

Some further reading on this, if you're interested, [here's a good question asked](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

PATH is a symbolic name usually associated to string values separated by a semicolons (where each string part is a directory name). This symbolic name (and its values) is handled by the operating system and could be modified by the end user through the some command line instruction like SET PATH=........ or through some kind of user interface configuration tool.

It is common practice for tools like compilers or other programming tools to look at this symbolic name and use the list of string values for searching files that are not directly available in the current folder used by the tools.

So, if an installation procedure set the PATH symbol in this way

```
SET PATH=%path%;C:\PROGRAM FILES\MYTOOLFOLDER;
```

it means, set the `PATH` symbol to the previous value (`%PATH%`) and add another string value to it (`C:\PROGRAM FILES\MYTOOLFOLDER`).

Then the tool, when it needs to search for a particular file or library, could read the PATH symbol values, split them at the semicolons and iteratively look at the directories listed one by one looking for the file required.

In C# programming, for example, the tool code could contain something like this

```
string pathSymbol = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
string[] pathFolders = pathSymbol.Split(';');
foreach(string folder in pathFolders)
{
    if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(folder, "mylibrary.dll"))
    {
        ..... do whatever you need to do with the file
    }
}
```

This example assumes a Windows environment.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense than what I originally had convinced myself it was..