# JDK8 for NetBeans 12.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, platform, netbeans-12

I'm trying to install JDK8 as a platform on NetBeans 12.2, but I keep getting this error message:

"Cannot detect and install the selected platform. The java or javac may not be executable."

Is there a way around this? Or is there a version of JDK8 that won't yield this error message?

Further: I should have mentioned that I'm on MACOS Big Sur.

Here's what I get with java -version in Terminal:

java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

And here's what I get with javac -version:

javac 15.0.2

Comment: I think I know how to answer your question. Can you tell me what output you get if you open cmd and type `java -version`.  Also, test `javac -version`.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant for your problem on NetBeans12.2, but note this known issue on macOS Big Sur with NetBeans 12.1: [Apache NetBeans 12.1 fails to run on Big Sur. Workaround: edit netbeans.conf and uncomment and set the JDK home path in the netbeans_jdkhome variable.](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb121/nb121.html)

Comment: @geekTechnique NetBeans uses its own approach for determining the version and location of the JDK to be used, so the results of calling __java__ or __javac__ from the command line aren't relevant. For example, you might see that Java can't be found from the command line yet Java within NetBeans works fine, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this message because the JDK executables haven't been added to your [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294504/significance-of-a-path-explained#:%7E:text=A%20PATH%20is%20a%20file,code%20you%20are%20using%20are.) as environment variables. Directly from the official java website, [here's a guide](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) on how to fix this problem.